# How to achieve below scenario in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access-2016

table1:

```
test1   test2   test3   rest1   rest2
1         a       z      21      82
2         s       z      26      81
2         a       z      54      82
```

Expected result:

```
rest1   rest2   Filed1  filed2
  21      82      test1   1
  26      81      test2   a
  54      82      test3   z
  21      82      test1   2
  26      81      test2   s
  54      82      test3   z
  21      82      test1   2
  26      81      test2   a
  54      82      test3   z
```

I tried transform, pivot, union, but unable to achieve the above.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: @Hille True, but in this case, I doubt the OP's query would help us to come up with an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but how should we help him without writing a functional code? I thought we should not write full code?

Comment: @Hille: As a general rule, yes, but it is not hard-edged - like here, where you hardly can help without writing the code.

Comment: Opinions will vary on this question, @Hille, but I think you are quite correct. It would be better every question author if they were required to supply a reasonable go at the problem, but in some tags (SQL especially) there are a lot of people who will do free work, which may not be ideal for the learning process of question authors. The best we can do is vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way to do this more gracefully in Access, e.g. using crosstabs, but one simple approach would be to just use unions:

```
SELECT rest1, rest2, 'test1' AS Filed1, test1 AS Filed 2 FROM table1 UNION ALL
SELECT rest1, rest2, 'test2', test2 FROM table1                      UNION ALL
SELECT rest1, rest2, 'test3', test3 FROM table1
```